# Automatic execute plugin after svn commit

Tags: maven, svn, maven-3, maven-plugin, mojo

Is it possible to execute maven plugin (created by me (for fun)) after or before commit from svn?

Maybe there is suitable maven lifecycle to things like this?

Thanks for help!

**Edit**
Can pre-commit hook execute maven plugin?

Comment: First why would you like to do so for which purpose? Apart from that it's not possible cause no life cycle exist for such things.

Comment: I just want to automatize some processes. That's not good for me. Maybe there is some way to go around the problem..

Comment: pre-commit hook will execute things on the SVN server itself, not on the dev machine.

Comment: On the server? pre- and post-commit hooks. On the client? No standard solution exists, but you can write your own shell script that wraps the svn client and does what you want.

Comment: A pre-commit hook as the ability to prevent you / someone else committing and it will block the svn client while it builds.  Also I'm not 100% certain that a pre-commit knows exactly what the file structure will look like as concurrent commits will not see each other... its not until the post-commit hook fires that you have access to a stable file system against a revision number.

Is it possible? Almost certainly yes.

Answer (score 0):

Remember this one simple fact about Subversion hooks:

> Subversion hooks run on the Subversion server and not on your local system and have no access to the user's local working directory and cannot manipulate that working directory in any way.

So, you have a pre-commit hook run some maven plugin on a pre-commit because it won't have access to the changes you've made.

Now, what is this Maven plugin doing? Is it running unit tests? Reformatting your code? Outputting some [pithy quotation](http://www.reichel.net/potpourri/cookie.html)? Why does this have to be run before the commit?

You can use a continuous integration tool (and I highly recommend that you use one) to run your Maven plugin after each commit, and then email the group responsible for the project if there are any issues. Yes, this will take place after the commit, but this is version control: Commits can be undone.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated a continuous integration tool is the way to go for any sizable work or team project.

However there are reasons why you might see continuous integration tool as overkill *(not least because it adds another tool to the ever growing stack of things to learn and you don't feel you have time for that right now)*

So it is of course possible to trigger builds from your svn server.  Remember that these will be compiled for whatever architecture the server is running.  If you're just compiling java then you'll be fine.

You'll need to use post-commit hooks as there are a number of problems with pre-commit hooks:

- Users committing to the SVN will have to wait for the hook to complete every time they commit.
- A failed build could cause the commit to fail (is that what you want?).
- Content from a commit isn't stable until it's committed (on a pre-commit hook, you don't yet have a stable version number.  Someone else starting a commit just after may manage to commit first especially if your built takes a while to complete).
- It's not easy to determine the exact state of files as they will be after the commit (see previous).

So if you use a post-commit hook things are much easier.

Look into `svnlook`.  This command can be used to interrogate changes from a commit: `svnlook changed ${1} -r ${2} > myTest.log` within the post-commit hook will print a list of changes out to a file for you.  You could easily search this to see if a directory has been touched in the last commit, then use `svn checkout` and `mvn deploy` to build that project.